# Update linked tables with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2000

I have an existing database with a table structure like this:

```
TABLE [Parent]
  [Parent_ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 

TABLE [ChildA]
  [ChildA_ID] INT
  [Parent_ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FK -> [Parent].[Parent_ID]

TABLE [ChildB]
  [ChildB_ID] INT
  [Parent_ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FK -> [Parent].[Parent_ID]
```

To support future functionality, I need link rows of `ChildA` and `ChildB` so that there is exactly one `ChildB` for each `ChildA`. The new structure should be

```
TABLE [ChildA]
  [ChildA_ID] INT
  [Parent_ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FK -> [Parent].[Parent_ID]

TABLE [ChildB]
  [ChildB_ID] INT
  [ChildA_ID] INT FK -> [ChildA].[ChildA_ID]
  [Parent_ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FK -> [Parent].[Parent_ID]
```

Now, both tables contain several rows in both the `ChildA` and `ChildB` tables that are nearly duplicates. For the sake of this question lets assume that the number of rows in each table is the same for any given `Parent_Id`. I need to pick a unique `ChildA` for each `ChildB`, even if I have to pick them at random.

This works for cases where there is exactly one row in each table:

```
UPDATE b
SET    [ChildA_ID] = a.[ChildA_ID]
FROM   [ChildB] b
       INNER JOIN [ChildA] a ON a.[Parent_ID] = b.[Parent_ID]
```

I don't have any other criteria to add to the `JOIN`. I think `ROW_NUMBER` would work, but this database is running on SQL Server 2000. How would I go about assigning a `ChildA_ID` to each `ChildB_ID` when there are multiple records?

Comment: Please note that after adding the requisite `ChildA_ID` to table `ChildB`, the fk reference to `Parent` is no longer required (because it can be derived through `ChildA`).  To get a row number, you could select/dump both children tables into temp tables with a new column - the `COUNT()` of children _before_ their id (expensive, though).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse `[ChildB].[Parent_ID]` is not longer necessary, but I'll have to leave it for backward compatibility. I'm thinking I could use a temp table / table variable with an `IDENTITY` field, but I'm not sure how to structure the script.

Comment: I initially thought of using an `IDENTITY` field too, but you'd have to reset it every time `Parent_ID` changed (because I'm willing to bet that you don't have _exactly_ the same count of a's and b's).  But yeah, that would otherwise work - and you can probably find other questions on here that do this.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse you're right, they're not *always* the same number, but usually they are. I can actually create duplicates of `[ChildB]` just to make them the same number if need be.